# For positive integers $n$, let $c_n$ be the smallest positive integer for which $n^{c_n} -1$ is divis by $210$. What is $c_1 + c_2 + \dots + c_{210}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> For positive integers $n$, let $c_n$ be the smallest positive integer for which $n^{c_n} -1$ is divisible by $210$, if such a positive integer exists, and $c_n = 0$ otherwise. What is $c_1 + c_2 + \dots + c_{210}$?

$n^{c_n}-1$ being divisible by $210$ is the same as saying that $n^{c_n} \equiv 1 \pmod {210}$ and since $c_n$ is the *smallest* such integer we have that $\operatorname{ord}_{210}(n)=c_n$.

We also have that $\operatorname{ord}_{210}(n) \mid \varphi(210)$ that is $c_n \mid 48$.

So $c_n$ can only be something of $1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16,24,48$.

How can I get further with the problem? I'm a bit stuck here.

Comment: I suggest:  try the same problem for smaller values than $210$.  Try $6$, or $30$, say.

Comment: Actually, $c_n\mid \operatorname{lcm}(2-1,3-1,5-1,7-1)=12.$ Think of chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Specifically, if $\gcd(n,210)=1,$ then $210\mid n^{12}-1,$ since it is divisible by $n-1, n^2-1, n^4-1,$ and $n^6-1,$ which are, in turn, divisible by $2,3,5,7.$

Comment: $c_n$ is not always well-defined. For example, $2^c-1$ is always odd, so $c_2$ is not well-defined. Perhaps you meant to impose the additional condition $(n,210)=1$? In that case, just sum the orders of the elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/210)^\times\cong \mathbb{Z}/\varphi(210)\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @lulu I think that for $6$ the sum is just $2$ since all $c_i's$ are zero except for $c_5$? For $c_5$ we have that $6 \mid 5^{c_5} -1$ and $5^2 -1 = 24$ is a multiple of $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Well, $c_1=1$ no matter what the modulus, yes?

Comment: @Mastrem  The problem specifies that $c_n=0$ if there is no order (so, for example, $c_2=0$).

Comment: @lulu Ah, I see. Also, I made a mistake: $(\mathbb{Z}/210\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/\varphi(210)\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think I made a mistake. The case for $6$ is probably $6$.

Comment: As others have remarked, best here is to invoke the Chinese Remainder Theorem and think of the problem mod $2,3,5,7$ separately.  The order of an  invertible element $\pmod {210}$ is just the lcm of those $4$ separate orders.

Comment: I'm trying to formulate this with the chinese remainder theorem, but I don't see exactly how I can get a system of congruences from this.

Comment: @Johansen, I don't think you're necessarily looking for a *system* of congruences here. The CRT has been mentioned in the sense of "the CRT gives you [info], what can you do with that info?" As lulu mentions, the CRT implies that $\text{ord}_{210}(n) = \text{lcm}(\text{ord}_{2}(n), \text{ord}_{3}(n), \text{ord}_{5}(n), \text{ord}_{7}(n))$, those being the factors of $210$. Now... where can you go with that?

Comment: @EricSnyder That will imply that $\text{ord}_{210}(n) \mid 12$ so $\text{ord}_{210}(n) = 1,2,3,4,6,12$.

Comment: @Johansen OK, good.  Now go a bit further with it--consider what it would be like to iterate over the integers in $[1,210]$. We *could* find $\text{ord}_210(n)$ for each $n$... or we could do the much simpler calculation of the four orders mod $2,3,5$, and $7$. Do you see how that can shorten our path? (Also consider which integers will have $c_n = 0$, and can you see how that's related?)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. OP never responded to further prompting, but I feel like the problem is interesting enough deserve a solution.

As above, we have $c_n = \text{ord}_{210}(n)$. (I'm just going to use $o_m(n)$ for the order for simplicity from here forward.) We know only $\varphi(210) = 48$ values of $n$ will in fact have a multiplicative order, and that for those that have one,
$$o_{210}(n) = \text{lcm}[o_2(n),o_3(n),o_5(n),o_7(n)]$$

The problem definition tells us that for $n$ that aren't units of $\mathbb{Z}/210\mathbb{Z},c_n=0$. Then:

- We can ignore modulo $2$, since the order will always be either $1$ or undefined.
- In modulo $3$, $o_3(n) = n \bmod 3$.
- In modulo $5$, $o_5(n) = 1,4,4,2$ for $n \equiv 1,2,3,4 \pmod 5$ respectively.
- In modulo $7$, the orders are $1,3,6,3,6,2$ for the consecutive residues.

Sadly, there's no elementary way to sum that up. So instead we have:

$$\sum^{210}_{n=1} c_n = \sum_{1 \le n \le 210}^{(n,210) = 1} \text{lcm}[n \bmod 3, o_5(n), o_7(n)]$$

Of course, this is best found via a computer program, but it you have to to it by hand, at least everything is in nice patterns.

Comment: Interestingly, if we write this as a function $f(m)$ where $m = 210$ for this case, but can vary, there are interesting properties. $f(210) = 329$, but also $f(104) = f(105) = f(112) = f(140) = f(144) = f(180) = 329$.

Comment: I guess the value only depends on the structure of the abelian group of units mod $n$.  Probably those are all isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Surely the function "sum of orders of abelian group" has been studied.  It should be "multiplicative" in the sense that $329 = 7 \cdot 47$ where the $7$ comes from the $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ factor and the $47$ comes from the all the $2$-groups.

Comment: Here's a paper that appears to work out an explicit formula for an arbitrary finite $p$-group: https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11693.  It looks like one of those things that's easy to calculate for a specific case, and fiddly to give a general expression for.

Comment: Very interesting! Group theory is something I still have only a little understanding of, sadly. I'll take a look at that paper though.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Eric Snyder's answer and comments, it's easier here to use the prime power structure of the *multiplicative* group $(\mathbb{Z}/210\mathbb{Z})^\times$:

$$ (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^\times \times (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^\times \times (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2^2\mathbb{Z})\times (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}).$$

As Mastrem pointed out initially, we just want to sum the orders of the elements of this group.  We factor any such order into the power of $2$ arising from the $2$-group factor and the power of $3$ arising from the $3$-group, and the sums of those orders factor through much like summing divisors.  More generally, if $\sigma(G)$ is the sum of the orders of $G$, and $|G|,|H|$ are relatively prime, then $\sigma(G\times H) = \sigma(G) \sigma(H)$.  So we can solve each of these factors separately.

For $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, there is one element of order $1$ and two of order $3$, so $\sigma(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}) = 7$.

For $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2^2\mathbb{Z}$, the maximum order is $4$.  There is one element of order $1$, and the only way to get order $4$ is to take one of the two generators of $\mathbb{Z}/2^2\mathbb{Z}$, with the other components being arbitrary.  That makes $8$ elements of order $4$ and the other $7$ have order $2$.  So $\sigma(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2^2\mathbb{Z}) = 4\cdot 8 + 2\cdot 7 + 1 = 47$.

This yields the expected answer of $\sigma((\mathbb{Z}/210\mathbb{Z})^\times) = 7\cdot 47 = 329$.